# Need help proving a limit using the definition of a limit.

Tags: limits, epsilon-delta

I know the definition of the limit and how it applies in this case, but I don't know how to reach the end of the proof. The limit is:

$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}{\dfrac{2n^2-3n+1}{n^2-n+7}}=2$

I got to:

$\dfrac{n+13}{n^2-n+7}<\epsilon$

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use that $$\frac{n+13}{n^2-n+7}<\frac{13}{n}$$ since $n>0$ we get by cross multiplication
$$n^2+13n<13(n^2-n+7)$$ and this is equivalent to $$0<12n^2-26n+91$$

Answer (score 0):

You could use [L'Hopital''s Rule](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule), i.e. derive both the nominator and the denominator of your second expression to see that it converges to 0. According to L'Hopital, the same holds for the original expression!